# Documenting parameters for macro generated methods with YARD

Tags: ruby, yard

Give the following input:

```
class A
  # @!macro [attach] add_setting
  #   @!attribute [rw] $1
  #   @!method $1=(value)
  def self.add_setting(setting)
  end

  # @param value [String] Hexadecimal representation of color
  add_setting :color
end
```

YARD 0.9.12 generates the following warning (new since ~> 0.8):

```
[warn]: @param tag has unknown parameter name: value
    in file `test.rb' near line 9
```

What is the correct way to structure this documentation to avoid the warning? (This pattern is used in [rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L90).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `rspec` uses this documentation and you can see that they specify using the defined `macro`

```
# @macro [attach] add_setting
#   @!attribute [rw] $1
#   @!method $1=(value)
# .....
# @macro add_setting
# Run examples over DRb (default: `false`). RSpec doesn't supply the DRb
# server, but you can use tools like spork.
add_setting :drb
```

If you notice the `@macro add_setting` declaration this tells `yard` when documenting this method use the `add_setting` `macro`. In this case `$1` means `drb` so it will document the `drb` attribute. (not the individual getter/setter methods)

As you can see when they are documenting these methods they do not declare a data type because these types may differ for the different documented methods. Instead they specify the default in the description of the method.

**Option 1** (not sure why it works)

Just define the getter and setter rather than using `!@attribute` declaration which would look like

```
class A
  # @!macro [attach] add_setting
  #   @!method $1
  #     @return [Object] the $1 of the a 
  #   @!method $1=(value)
  def self.add_setting(setting)
  end
  # @param value [String] Hexadecimal representation of color
  add_setting :color
end
```

The `@return` is important or the warning comes back

**Option 2**

If you really wanted this functionality you could use `@overload` which would look like

```
class A
  # @!macro [attach] add_setting
  #   @!method $1
  #     @return [Object] the $1 of the a
  #   @!method $1=(value)
  def self.add_setting(setting)
  end
  # @overload color=(value)
  #   @param value [String] Hexadecimal representation of color
  # @macro add_setting
  add_setting :color
  add_setting :name
end
```

This will cause the getter method for `name` and `color` to be documented as:

- name => Object

  - Returns the name of the a
- color => Object

  - Returns the color of the a

but the setter methods will look like

- name=(value) => Object
- color=(value) => Object

  - Parameters:
  - value(String) -- Hexadecimal representation of color

because we overloaded `color=`.

That being said this doesn't really help you as it would probably consist of individually documenting the methods anyway.

Other options:

- Ignore the warnings
- quite all warnings completely `-q`
- Checkout this [Thread](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/1007)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand what was going on.